# Does a Kohen have to seek the same critria for a peligesh as he would for a wife?

Tags: halacha, kohen-priest

Does a Kohen have to seek the same halachic criteria for a peligesh as he would for a wife?

Case one:
He is not married (so he's not seeking polygamy). He's simply seeking a "lesser-married status" for the purpose of being with someone who is otherwise not permitted to him.

Case two: He *is* looking for a second wife. (If so, this raises a new and greater problem with the concept in general: would any child from a relationship with *any* married man and a peligesh be considered a mamzer?)

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's a serious question and, while would not have any ramifications now, still is interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rambam says in הלכות מלכים ומלחמות פרק ד that only a King may marry a Pilegesh.

```
אבל ההדיוט אסור בפילגש
```

Since a Cohen cannot be a King (הלכות מלכים ומלחמות פרק א), **there is no basis for the question according to the Rambam.**

Comment: This answer is incredibly not interesting and seems to miss the point.

Comment: So, other words ONLY a king would have one? that simplifies things a bit.

Comment: What about a Hasmonean king? (They were kohanim.)

Comment: Where in the torah does it say that only king can have concubines?

Comment: @JimThio, if the Rambam says so, then he learned it from the Talmud which learned it from a verse the Torah, or an oral tradition. The commentators on the Rambam have provided a source for every single one of his statements.

Comment: @DannySchoemann what if instead of "Pilegesh", the OP used the word "Shifchah", what does Halacha say about it?

Comment: @ninamag - only a Jewish-owned slave may marry a Shifcha (who is a Jewish owned slave herself.)